# Dialog between Android and iPhone

Tags: webrtc, opentok, tokbox

Good day, everyone.

I have some problem with tokbox, when trying make connection between iphone (ios11) and android (7.1.2, chrome 63)

i get Video format not supported with any andorid device (galaxy s7, lenovo, xiaomi redmi 4x, any android studio emulators)

i have no idea what the problem is.
according tokbox site, problem in h264 support on my devices. 
https://support.tokbox.com/hc/en-us/articles/115001579624-Chrome-on-Android-does-not-work-with-Safari-projects

but my procs is qualcomm and samsung, and chrome version is 63.

is there anybody, who have same problems? what i'm doing wrong? can be the problem in my code? i guess no, cause this is tokbox system message.

please, i'm waiting for some opinions!

Answer (score 1):

This is a known issue with Android devices that we've reported to the WebRTC bug tracker: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/webrtc/issues/detail?id=8584

We're working on a solution but unfortunately I cannot give a time estimate.

Regards,
Aiham